# Sync 'Other' Address using CRM 2011 Outlook Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to sync this field (the 'other' address)?  All other fields seem to be syncing across to users, but the 'other' address seems to only be local.

Also, is there a way of customizing the From shown for the CRM contact plugin?  It does not display any customized fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Outlook/Offline filters. You need to set them up so that the Address entity is also pulled to the local database.

Comment: Right, but as far as I know, in CRM there is Home address and Business address only.  How would I map 'other' to something in crm?